# Sending Ajax Request to Get Builder List on keyup but after some time, i got response too many redirects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using below code to get builder list auto-suggestions when user start typing.  I gives proper result but after sometime, i am getting error message too many redirects.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).on("keyup","#builder_name", function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 2){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home-loan-balance-transfer",
            data: "step=search_builder&builder_detail="+$(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.status == 'success'){
                    $("#builder-list").html(response.html);
                    $("#builder-list").removeClass('hide');
                } else{
                    $("#builder-list").addClass('hide');
                }
            }
        });
    }   
});
```

Comment: Could you show  your `php` code?

Comment: Might want to put a `timeout` in there - as it stands you could be making several requests a second depending on how fast you type.

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav `dataType:'json'` means the expected response from the server is json